# Receive Arduino commands from Bluetooth module

Tags: arduino, bluetooth

First off this is my first Arduino project but I have coded basic c++ before. Anyway I am struggling to get the Arduino to acknowledge when save data to a variable. I know it's receiving the data but its not getting appended to my data variable. Here's the code and if I could get a basic explanation of what I did wrong I would appreciate it.

```cpp
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial BTserial(0, 1);

//declair pins

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  //setup pins
}

void loop() {
  String data;
  bool run = false;
  
  data = "";
  while (Serial.available()) {
    char inChar = (char)Serial.read();
    Serial.print(inChar); //I know it is getting the sent data because prints here
    if (inChar == '\n') {
      Serial.print("Received Command: ");
      if (data == "")
        Serial.print("Data is NULL"); //this always prints too
      Serial.print(data);
      Serial.print('\n');
      run = true;
      break;
    } else {
      data += inChar;
    }
  }

  if(run) {
     //do stuff
  } 
}
```

I know there are plenty of websites I could copy paste from but I want to make my own and understand what I did wrong. I did read them though.

For example if I send `command` from my phone the output would be

```
command
Received Command: Data is NULL
```

Comment: loop function runs continuously. In this code, "data" is redefined empty in every loop.. What you want to do is assign the incoming data to the variable?

Comment: Do you have a sample of the data that you get from inChar/serial read?

Comment: @mbema I added a example to the post

Comment: @omfaer thanks for the tip it I miss understood how often the loop worked.

Answer (score 0):

The following segment will always appear null here on the first loop unless you receive characters other than newline when your serial begins listening because the program executes from top to bottom and you haven't given data a value yet here.

```cpp
if (data == "") {
  Serial.print("Data is NULL"); //this always prints too
}
```

P.S. This expression

```cpp
String data;
data = "";
```

can be simplified to

```cpp
String data ="";
```

More efficient.

I'll try to provide more information if I can figure out the issue once I get some sample data.

Comment: Theoretically when I send data from the Arduino it will see if the character is \n and if it's not it will append it to data with the else statement. I experimented with puting a print statement in the else loop and can confirm that that section of code does get ran the right number of times.